# How to Resolve the Errors between ABS and UND

Tags: c, assembly

This error occurs when I execute 'make all'

```
root@VM-4-14-ubuntu:~/homemadeOS/menghanOS# make all
i686-elf-gcc -c arch/x86/boot.S -o build/obj/arch/x86/boot.S.o
arch/x86/boot.S: Assembler messages:
arch/x86/boot.S:6: Error: can't resolve `0' {*ABS* section} - `L0' {*UND* section}
```

I don't know how to solve it

so I have rewritten the boot.S file

but it doesn't help
the multiboot.h

```
#define MB_MAGIC 0x1BADB002
#define MB_ALIGNED_4K_MEM_MAP 0x03
#define CHECKSUM(flags) -(MB_MAGIC + flags)
```

the boot.S

```
#include "multiboot.h"
//define multiboot`s header
.section .multiboot
   .long MB_MAGIC
   .long MB_ALIGNED_4K_MEN_MAP
   .long CHECKSUM(MB_ALIGNED_4K_MEN_MAP)
 //clear area
.section .bss
//According to System V ABI, the stack must be aligned at 16 bytes boundry
   .align 16
   //16318 bytes fill with 0
   .skip 16318, 0
   stack_top:
 
  //code segment
.section .text
   .global start_
   start_:
     movl $stack_top, %esp
     call _kernel_main
     //stop CPU
     cli
   j_:
     hlt
     jmp j_
```

I would like to know about ABS and UND in order to solve this problem

Comment: What is the content of `multiboot.h`? `UND` means undefined.